# Syntax for List(of T) Type Naming/Conversion for ListBox DragDrop

Tags: vb.net, types, drag-and-drop, listbox

I am trying to create a generic routine for drag and drop of ListBox.Selecteditems, taking the ListBox.SelectedItems from the source and creating a List(of T). In order to do that, I need to be able to obtain the Type of the underlying ListBox.SelectedValue, and believe that I am able to achieve that using the following line:

```
Dim lbxType As Type = (sender.SelectedValue).GetType
```

Here is my subroutine in context:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
  If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 OrElse e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then Return
  Dim lbxType As Type = (sender.SelectedValue).GetType
  Dim selItems As New List(Of lbxType)   <- FAILS! it fails here - will not compile
  {…more code…}
End Sub
```

Beyond this, evidently, I do not know the syntax on how to create a List(Of T) of that type as shown in the code above (see line marked 'FAILS'). I know that I can always get a string TypeName() and then do a Select/Case but I am hoping that there is a more "modular" way. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you kindly!

**EDIT #1 for Result**

```
Private Sub LbxTestDragStart(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown, ListBox3.MouseDown
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    If lbx.SelectedItems.Count = 0 OrElse e.Button <> Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then Return
    Dim dragLst = CType(GetType(List(Of )).
        MakeGenericType(lbx.SelectedItems(0).GetType()).
        GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).
        Invoke(Nothing), IList)
    For Each si In lbx.SelectedItems
        dragLst.Add(si)
    Next
    lbx.DoDragDrop(dragLst, DragDropEffects.Copy)
End Sub

Private Sub Lbx_DragEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox2.DragEnter, ListBox3.DragEnter
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    'we assume only one type of format in each listbox
    Dim fmt = e.Data.GetFormats(0)
    Dim fmtName As String = TypeName(e.Data.GetData(fmt(0))(0))
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    'id specific target listbox to set DD effects as this is a multi-purpose sub
    'in this select case, for testing, listbox3 is noticeably absent
    Select Case lbx.Name
        Case "ListBox1"
            'do something if ListBox1
        Case "ListBox2"
            If fmtName = "ClientLocation" Then e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Lbx_DragDrop(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles ListBox2.DragDrop, ListBox3.DragDrop
    Dim lbx = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Dim fmt = e.Data.GetFormats(0)
    Dim fmtName As String = TypeName(e.Data.GetData(fmt(0))(0))
    'setup for processing of dropped items
    Select Case lbx.Name
        Case "ListBox2"
            If fmtName = "ClientLocation" Then
                For Each item In e.Data.GetData(fmt(0))
                    lbx.Items.Add(item)
                Next
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to convert the `Object` it is stored in with the `SelectedObjectCollection`. Do you know the type it is?

Comment: to create a generic dynamically, you will need to use Reflection.  But why not just drag/drop a collection?  What Type is in the ListBox?   You also probably want to initiate DD with other than just R Mouse down

Comment: The type is class type from a db - "ClientLocation" to be specific. @Plutonix - could you provide a line or two that I could use to continue my research? Regarding other than R mouse button down, I'd like to but using L Mouse deselects currently selected. I'll play with that a little later once I determine I can get the rest of it working. :)

Comment: @Plutonix - I will also investigate dragging the collection. As a more sophisticated DD is somewhat new to me (more than just strings) I may be looking at this entirely wrong. I figured that I would have the same problem in the DD or the drop, hence my question.

Comment: I would think the DD trigger would be RButton down PLUS  MouseMove so they are actually dragging rather than maybe looking for a context menu.  The items spend so little time between the drag and the drop that it is hardly worth it: the drop target could check if the Type is accepted which it ought to do anyway.

Comment: Now I understand what you are saying about the R Mouse button. I agree. I will work on the drop target to see how I can do this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the comments, there is so little time between the Drag and Drop that it really isnt worth creating a generic list.  The Drop target should check the Type dropped so that only `ClientLocation` items are accepted and `CircusClown` items are not.

That said, here is way to still avoid creating a list dynamically (`Animal` is a Type stand in for your `ClientLocation`):

```
Private dragList As List(Of Animal)

Private Sub lb_MouseMove(sender ...
    If lbMouseDown Then

        dragList = New List(Of Animal)
        For Each a As Animal In lb.Items
            dragList.Add(a)
        Next

        lb.DoDragDrop(dragList, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        ...
```

Your code pretends like it does not know what Type is in the ListBox.  If that is perhaps because it can be one of several types - perhaps the contents change (?), then you have to resort to `Reflection`:

```
' get the Type for a List(of T)
Dim genType = GetType(List(Of ))
' get the type in the listbox
Dim t As Type = lb.SelectedItems(0).GetType() 'GetType(Animal) 
' get the "combined" type for List(of ) + ListType
Dim LType = genType.MakeGenericType(t)     ' == List(of Animal)
```

At this point, you can go two ways:

```
' METHOD 1: using a ctor
Dim ctor As ConstructorInfo = LType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
Dim theList = CType(ctor.Invoke(Nothing), IList)

' METHOD 2: using System.Activator:
Dim theList = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(LType), IList)

' EITHER WAY, xfer items - see note
For Each aa In lb.SelectedItems
    theList.Add(aa)
Next
lb.DoDragDrop(theList, DragDropEffects.Copy)
```

That is formatted for illustrative purposes.  You can chain the methods using the `GetConstructor` version and avoid all the temp Type vars:

```
Dim dragLst = CType(GetType(List(Of )).
    MakeGenericType(lb.SelectedItems(0).GetType()).
    GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).
    Invoke(Nothing), IList)
```

Note:  Typically, you would want to add the item that the mouse is over when the DragDrop starts - the user is going to sort of expect that.  That item may not be part of SelectedItems and they may want to only drag that one item. This means finding the item under e.X, e.Y

The code just uses `SelectedItems` for simplicity.

Comment: My goodness - thank you so much for your time. This is awesome. I am digesting this all and will get back soon.

Comment: Your help has been awesome. Below is the code that I will be using for my multi-purpose dragDrop subs, in case it can help anyone else. :) It assumes one thing - that there is only one format type coming from the source ListBox. I think that it is relatively safe, hopefully not too "hacky". Your "dragLst" declaration allowed me to identify the type coming from the source to provide feedback to the user. I could have, as you suggested, just dragged a collection and sorted it out on the drop but providing feedback is much better. **See edit #1 for code**. Thanks again!